# SSD hard drives on IBM x3550 ServeRAID 8k

Tags: ssd, hardware-raid

I have 4 SSD drives in an IBM x3550 using the installed ServeRAID 8k card in a RAID 10 setup. I"m not having any issues, but reading the ServeRAID may not support SSD and if I should stick with it or use Linux software RAID? I can use the Adaptec utility arcconf to read the RAID, but is that reliable info against this ServeRAID? Also concerned 'SSD: No' in the output ...

```
[root@vhost3 cmdline]# arcconf GETCONFIG 1
Controllers found: 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Controller information
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Controller Status                        : Optimal
   Channel description                      : SAS/SATA
   Controller Model                         : IBM ServeRAID 8k    
   Controller Serial Number                 : 383B889
   Controller World Wide Name               : 5005076B0383B889
   Physical Slot                            : 0
   Installed memory                         : 256 MB
   Copyback                                 : Disabled
   Background consistency check             : Enabled
   Background consistency check period      : 30
   Automatic Failover                       : Enabled
   Host bus type                            : unknown
   Host bus speed                           : 0 MHz
   Host bus link width                      : 0 bit(s)/link(s)
   Stayawake period                         : Disabled
   Spinup limit internal drives             : 0
   Spinup limit external drives             : 0
   Defunct disk drive count                 : 0
   Logical devices/Failed/Degraded          : 1/0/0
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Controller Version Information
   --------------------------------------------------------
   BIOS                                     : 5.2-0 (15421)
   Firmware                                 : 5.2-0 (15421)
   Driver                                   : 1.2-1 (40709)
   Boot Flash                               : 5.1-0 (15411)
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Controller Battery Information
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Status                                   : Optimal
   Over temperature                         : No
   Capacity remaining                       : 100 percent
   Time remaining (at current draw)         : 1 days, 8 hours, 0 minutes

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Logical device information
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Logical device number 0
   Logical device name                      : RAID10
   Block Size of member drives              : Unknown
   RAID level                               : 10
   Unique Identifier                        : D9A4A93B
   Status of logical device                 : Optimal
   Size                                     : 234342400 MB
   Parity space                             : 0 MB
   Stripe-unit size                         : 256 KB
   Read-cache setting                       : Disabled
   Read-cache status                        : Off
   Write-cache setting                      : On when protected by battery/ZMM
   Write-cache status                       : On
   Partitioned                              : Yes
   Protected by Hot-Spare                   : No
   Bootable                                 : Yes
   Failed stripes                           : No
   Power settings                           : Disabled
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Logical device segment information
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Group 0, Segment 0                       : Present (Controller:1,Enclosure:0,Slot:0) 50026B7253031131
   Group 0, Segment 1                       : Present (Controller:1,Enclosure:0,Slot:1) 50026B72530310C1
   Group 1, Segment 0                       : Present (Controller:1,Enclosure:0,Slot:2) 50026B725303131D
   Group 1, Segment 1                       : Present (Controller:1,Enclosure:0,Slot:3) 50026B7253030FEA


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Physical Device information
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      Device #0
         Device is a Hard drive
         State                              : Online
         Block Size                         : Unknown
         Supported                          : Yes
         Transfer Speed                     : SATA 3.0 Gb/s
         Reported Channel,Device(T:L)       : 0,0(0:0)
         Reported Location                  : Enclosure 0, Slot 3
         Reported ESD(T:L)                  : 2,0(0:0)
         Vendor                             : KINGSTON
         Model                              : 
         Firmware                           : 
         Serial number                      : 50026B7253030FEA
         Reserved Size                      : 11642117 KB
         Used Size                          : 0 MB
         Unused Size                        : 29121942 MB
         Total Size                         : 29133311 MB
         Write Cache                        : Disabled (write-through)
         FRU                                : None
         S.M.A.R.T.                         : No
         S.M.A.R.T. warnings                : 0
         SSD                                : No
         NCQ status                         : Disabled
      Device #1
         Device is a Hard drive
         State                              : Online
         Block Size                         : Unknown
         Supported                          : Yes
         Transfer Speed                     : SATA 3.0 Gb/s
         Reported Channel,Device(T:L)       : 0,1(1:0)
         Reported Location                  : Enclosure 0, Slot 1
         Reported ESD(T:L)                  : 2,0(0:0)
         Vendor                             : KINGSTON
         Model                              : 
         Firmware                           : 
         Serial number                      : 50026B72530310C1
         Reserved Size                      : 11642117 KB
         Used Size                          : 0 MB
         Unused Size                        : 29121942 MB
         Total Size                         : 29133311 MB
         Write Cache                        : Disabled (write-through)
         FRU                                : None
         S.M.A.R.T.                         : No
         S.M.A.R.T. warnings                : 0
         SSD                                : No
         NCQ status                         : Disabled
      Device #2
         Device is a Hard drive
         State                              : Online
         Block Size                         : Unknown
         Supported                          : Yes
         Transfer Speed                     : SATA 3.0 Gb/s
         Reported Channel,Device(T:L)       : 0,2(2:0)
         Reported Location                  : Enclosure 0, Slot 2
         Reported ESD(T:L)                  : 2,0(0:0)
         Vendor                             : KINGSTON
         Model                              : 
         Firmware                           : 
         Serial number                      : 50026B725303131D
         Reserved Size                      : 11642117 KB
         Used Size                          : 0 MB
         Unused Size                        : 29121942 MB
         Total Size                         : 29133311 MB
         Write Cache                        : Disabled (write-through)
         FRU                                : None
         S.M.A.R.T.                         : No
         S.M.A.R.T. warnings                : 0
         SSD                                : No
         NCQ status                         : Disabled
      Device #3
         Device is a Hard drive
         State                              : Online
         Block Size                         : Unknown
         Supported                          : Yes
         Transfer Speed                     : SATA 3.0 Gb/s
         Reported Channel,Device(T:L)       : 0,3(3:0)
         Reported Location                  : Enclosure 0, Slot 0
         Reported ESD(T:L)                  : 2,0(0:0)
         Vendor                             : KINGSTON
         Model                              : 
         Firmware                           : 
         Serial number                      : 50026B7253031131
         Reserved Size                      : 11642117 KB
         Used Size                          : 0 MB
         Unused Size                        : 29121942 MB
         Total Size                         : 29133311 MB
         Write Cache                        : Disabled (write-through)
         FRU                                : None
         S.M.A.R.T.                         : No
         S.M.A.R.T. warnings                : 0
         SSD                                : No
         NCQ status                         : Disabled
      Device #4
         Device is an Enclosure services device
         Reported Channel,Device(T:L)       : 2,0(0:0)
         Enclosure ID                       : 0
         Expander ID                        : 0
         Enclosure Logical Identifier       : 5345532044455620
         Type                               : SES2
         Vendor                             : IBM
         Model                              : SAS 4 DRIVE BP
         Firmware                           : 1.10
         Status of Enclosure services device
            Speaker status                  : Not available
```

Comment: Well, it also says `S.M.A.R.T.: No`...

Comment: Ah yes, as well, guess that needs to be enabled in the BIOS?